# How to get `$promise.then` value by return in the `$resource`?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

From one of the service, I am `retuning` a back-end output. I am getting values, but how to get the result values from the returned object?

here is my code :

```
var queryConractorInfo = function ( server, contractorParams ) {

            return server.contractorInfo.get(contractorParams)
                  .$promise.then(function ( contractorInfo ) {

                    return contractorInfo;

            })

}
```

here is my call :

```
console.log( queryConractorInfo( server, contractorParams) );
```

here is the output I am getting :

```
{
  "$$state": {
    "status": 1,
    "value": { // i want to get this from returned object.
      "ActualPercentage": "33.5",
      "AllWeeks": [
        "/Date(1446930000000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1446498000000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1439154000000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1438635600000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1436043600000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1431550800000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1389733200000+0300)/",
        "/Date(1332277200000+0300)/"
      ]
}
}
}
```

I tried like this:

```
var queryConractorInfo = function ( server, contractorParams ) {

            return server.contractorInfo.get(contractorParams)
                  .$promise.then(function ( contractorInfo ) {

                    return contractorInfo.promise;
                    //adding promise but not working

            })

}
```

Comment: how is defined the `server` var ?

Comment: i am getting as a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your case, you seem to be stuck on returning something.

That's not how it works with promises. Returning from a promise callback (or resolve function) will only pass data to the next .then() function. You can chain many then-calls

```
var queryContractorInfo = function ( server, contractorParams ) {

    return server.contractorInfo.get(contractorParams)
        .$promise.then(function ( contractorInfo ) {

            // This will return to the next .then() call
            return contractorInfo;
        })
        .then(function(contractorInfo) {

            // Another then call, understand?
        });
}
```

It basicly works like this

```
// Outer variable, initialized to null (use an empty object if you prefer)
var queryContractorInfo = null;

server.contractorInfo.get(contractorParams)
    .$promise.then(function ( contractorInfo ) {

        // Now I can set queryContractorInfo
        queryContractorInfo = contractorInfo;

        // You can return, but you don't need to, if this is the final then
    });
```

The queryContractorInfo is empty, as long as the query is in progress. When you get a result, the variable is set to the result data. In the then function you could now trigger further functions, if you want to work with this variable.

Comment: agree. so we can't return the values at all is it? or any other workaround is there to return? ( I came to know about `then`'s nature )

Comment: No, sorry, return doesn't work. But if you're working with angular, and $scope, you'd just set the value of a scope variable to your query result (contractorInfo). Maybe you can explain your use case, or why you'd need to have the results in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear on what you are trying to achieve but this should help you.
What I think is that you want to return the JSON object from the function you are getting it?

Suppose you call the function as

```
myFuncToGetJSON().then(function(result){
    //result is the JSON object you are expecting
});
```

And in the function where you get the JSON

```
function myFuncToGetJSON(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); // create a deferred object
    //do steps to generate JSON
    deferred.resolve(theJSONYouHaveGenerated);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

More help **[HERE](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)**

Comment: Yes, I agree. But using the deffered as well i din't get the result. instead i got the promise object only. i am using angular `$resouce` as my data provider

Comment: @3gwebtrain see edit. you need to return the promise object. i have been using this and it works for me

Comment: sure let me try your approach